# GWT Error: "Class is used in Gin, but not available in GWT client code"

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwtp

Ok I'm not very seasoned in GWT yet and this is an error that has been bugging me since the I started using GWT and it just keeps coming and going.

I'm using the [Arcbees GWTP Framework](http://www.arcbees.com/#!/products/gwtp) in Spring. My code is very simple. I have simple POJO like so

```
public class EmailTask implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2395809310736629787L;

private Integer publisherId;
private String targetPublisherId;

public Integer getPublisherId() {
    return publisherId;
}

public void setPublisherId(Integer publisherId) {
    this.publisherId = publisherId;
}

public String getTargetPublisherId() {
    return targetPublisherId;
}

public void setTargetPublisherId(String targetPublisherId) {
    this.targetPublisherId = targetPublisherId;
}
}
```

In my Presenter class I'm passing an instance of this POJO using an Asynchronous call to a controller like so.

```
@Inject TaskServiceAsync taskServiceAsync;

private void myTask(){
    taskServiceAsync.executeTask(emailTaskInstance, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) {
                    Window.alert("Success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    Window.alert("Failure!");
                }
            });  
}
```

The Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/task")
public class TaskController extends BaseRemoteService implements TaskService {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -325150527276255072L;

    @Override
    public String executeTask(EmailTask emailTask) {
         //TODO: Doing something here
    }
}
```

As you can see, nothing too flashy. But I get the following error on Compile.

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) @ statistics ---

[INFO] Compiling module de.it2media.dps.statistics.DPSStatistics

[INFO]    Ignored 8 units with compilation errors in first pass.

[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.

[INFO]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DesktopGinjector'

[INFO]       Rebinding com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DesktopGinjector

[INFO]          Invoking generator 
com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator

[INFO]             [WARN] Class de.it2media.dps.statistics.server.jobs.EmailTask is used in Gin, but not available in GWT client code.

[INFO]             [ERROR] Error injecting de.it2media.dps.statistics.client.application.settings.SettingsPresenter$MyProxy: Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for de.it2media.dps.statistics.client.application.settings.SettingsPresenter$MyProxy
```

Forgive my simplistic complain, but I don't get what I'm doing wrong here. I have written similar code before and it has worked perfectly. Can someone please explain what the error `Class is used in Gin, but not available in GWT client code` even means? Do I have to autowire something somewhere somehow?

Answer (score 1):

First you should set the logLevel in your GWT running onfiguration to `TRACE`.

Using TRACE will show you errors with class-name and line number.

And the message tells you, that the class `de.it2media.dps.statistics.server.jobs.EmailTask`
is used by GIN (client side), but is not part of the source code, which will be compiled by GWT.

Put the `EmailTask` class in the shared package and the message should be gone.

Comment: The package itself of EmailTask should tell you something is wrong since it is in the `server` package. Either like this answer says, move it to shared or client (depending on how it is actually expected to be used), or stop referencing it from your client code and find a different way to build the feature.